# searching table and finding record

Tags: vb.net, search, sql-update

i am doing a self study on programming.  trying to develop a point of sale.
i am currently struggling with searching a table and finding an item from my inventory table and then throwing the item into my posinvoicedetails table with a default qty of 1

i cannot understand how to open connection on two different tables and search one and update the other at the same time.

can someone please expalin logic behind this.  i will try and figure out code thereafter.

i can open one table and search item in datagrid view and update records.

thanks

Comment: Sorry, not a tutorial site. You should do your search then try to write code. If your code doesn't work and you are unable to find the reason will be happy to help you.

Comment: You don't open a connection to a table, you open a connection to a database. And you don't search and update at the same time, the process is sequential, you first search and then update.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague so it's hard to guess what you want exactly. But this is what I think you're looking for.

1. Open the connection to the database .
2. Query it to search the specific table(the one you want to search) for what you're looking for.
3. Close the connection.
4. Open the connection again.
5. update the other table.

P.S. Through all of this, it should be the same database that you're connecting to but different tables within it.

Also, you need this code to connect to the database:

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
dataFile = "C:\Users\file.accdb"
connString = provider & dataFile
myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
```